# spring boot - springfox-boot-starter integration giving 404 with no error

Tags: spring-data-jpa, java-19, springfox-boot-starter

Java Version: 19.0.1
Springboot: 3.0.1

using dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Swagger configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())
      .build();
  }
```

There is no error, application is starting normally, but when visiting

`http://localhost:8060/swagger-ui` it is 404.

if I am using `@EnableSwagger2` then it is showing error while starting application that decencies are not available.

I followed [swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api), seems `@EnableSwagger2` annotation is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`springfox-boot-starter` version `3.0.0` seems not to support Spring Boot 3. Consider switching to [SpringDoc v2](https://springdoc.org/v2/) which does support it.